# How to filter grafana dashboard with greater than and less than operators?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-templating

I'm working on a project where I'm using Grafana and InfluxdB. I was able to get all the required values to grafana.

In my response I have a filed with value less than and greater than zero. I want to add a filter where user can select the type of operation.

Any recommendation on how to crack this.

So far I have tried..

I created a Variable (constant value 0, which i tried to use in my dashboard query with less than or greater than operator. As soon as I select my variable, the operator gets changed to 'equal to' or 'not equal to'.

By providing the value directly in the query works fine.

Query reflected Using the variable which i created as constant

```
SELECT "servicename" AS "Service Name", "topic" AS "Topic", "type" AS "Type", "count" AS "Count" FROM "KafkaLag" WHERE ("servicename" =~ /^$servicename$/ AND "topic" =~ /^$topic$/ AND "type" =~ /^$type$/ AND "count" =~ /^$Greater_than_zero$/) AND $timeFilter ORDER BY time DESC
```

Query reflected using value directly without any variable

```
SELECT "servicename" AS "Service Name", "topic" AS "Topic", "type" AS "Type", "count" AS "Count" FROM "KafkaLag" WHERE ("servicename" =~ /^$servicename$/ AND "topic" =~ /^$topic$/ AND "type" =~ /^$type$/ AND "count" > 0) AND $timeFilter ORDER BY time DESC
```

From the below table I need a way to put a dynamic filter on field_2 where I can get greater than zero values when required.

```
time | field_1 | field_2 
  t1 |   v1    |    0 
  t1 |   v2    |    2 
  t2 |   v3    |    0 
  t2 |   v4    |    12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from <table/measurement name> where field_2 > 0;
```

This query will filter data as per you need.

Comment: Steephen, this will restrict from the query side. I'm trying to have a more dynamic query, where in future i can increase my list of filter like (0,100,150,200).

Answer (score 0):

This may be late answer but this is how I have done it earlier. Create a variable `count`, type "custom". Then, use that variable as below in query-

```
SELECT "service_name" FROM service  WHERE ("count" >=$count) AND $timeFilter
```