# Filtering on integer range

Tags: grafana, influxdb, micrometer

We're running a Java service, logging metrics with [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) to InfluxDB and using Grafana to visualize it. Micrometer only supports string tag/values, but I've stored an integer as a string value, `query_span` and want to filter on that in Grafana.

This is what I've point-n-clicked myself to in Grafana:

```sql
SELECT sum("value") FROM "db_read"
WHERE ("short_name" = 'app' AND "environment" =~ /^$site$/
        AND "query_span" > '1' AND "query_span" <= '7')
        AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time(5m) fill(null)
```

The `query_span` part does not yield any data. Dropping the single-quotes doesn't work either. When I set the lower part of the interval to `"query_span" >= '2'` instead, I get some hits. Which leads me to believe some kinda string-to-string compare is going on (and the 'equal' part of 'greater or equal' returns true when `=="2"`). I see Influx supports [casting selected fields](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#cast-operations), bit I don't understand how to cast in the WHERE clause (naïve attempt failed).

**Note:** this is not a clone of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648433/how-to-filter-grafana-dashboard-with-greater-than-and-less-than-operators), distinct, Grafana/InfluxDB question. (Oh do I miss the good ol' days where these disclaimers were superfluous! :)

**Edit:** regex filtering works but is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course regexp will be working with string, but math comparison `>`,`<`,`<=`,`>=` doesn't - you need float/int type for that. If you use `<`,`<` on the the strings, then you will get lexicographic order. See: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/language/operators/#string-operators

I would say regexp is the best option for your use case (if you have low cardinality). You need to define allowed range explicitly, e.g. 4-9:

```
"query_span" =~ /^[4|5|6|7|8|9]$/
```

But of course proper InfluxDB schema with floats will be the best option.